# Dropbox not starting - Ubuntu 13.04 server eddition

Tags: server, dropbox

I am running a 32 bit installation of Ubuntu 13.04 Server edition and  watching `top` shows nothing. What i did was run:

`cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -`

then

`~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`

But after this command - **NOTHING** happens at all, ever ...

When I run top in another terminal and watch it, an ssh command starts and instantly stops and there's nothing else.

Whats going on?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on a small Dell Mini.

This was the problem I had. When I booted up 13.04 the Dropbox symbol did not appear in the top toolbar and Dropbox could not sync.

This is how I fixed it. I opened System monitor. (To find this Just put 'System monitor' in the Dash search engine. If it is not installed then install it from Ubuntu Software Centre.)

In System Monitor, run 'processes' and find Dropbox in the list. It will say it is running normally. Quit it - force quit it. Close system monitor. Then open Dropbox  (either from the launcher or from Dash) This time the symbol will reappear in your top toolbar and everything will work as it should.

Regards Mike Clifford

Comment: In the title, the OP says he is running Ubuntu _server_